# Multiple Formats in one cell using c#

Tags: c#, excel

I want to have mutple format types in one cell in my workbook.  For example I want my A1 cell to display " **Name:** Aaron Kruger ".  When I programmatically add the name "Aaron Kruger" to the template, it automatically makes it bold.  So instead it looks like this " **Name:Aaron Kruger** ". So I want Bold and non-bold both in the same cell.  And maybe in the future I will want two different text sizes in the same cell.
Thanks,
Aaron Kruger

*Here is the function I created:*

```
    public void inputData(int row, int column, string cellName, System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox, Excel.Worksheet sheet)
    {
        sheet.Cells[row, column] = sheet.get_Range(cellName, Type.Missing).Text + " " + textBox.Text; // adds value to sheet
    }
```

*Here are the arguments I pass in:*

```
        inputData(5, 1, "A5", tbTagNumber, xlSheet);
        inputData(6, 1, "A6", tbCustomer, xlSheet);
        inputData(7, 1, "A5", tbDataFile, xlSheet);
        inputData(3, 6, "F3", tbJobNumber, xlSheet);
        inputData(4, 6, "F4", tbMeterSN, xlSheet);
        inputData(6, 6, "F6", tbPO, xlSheet);
        inputData(7, 6, "F7", tbFlowplate, xlSheet);
        inputData(4, 9, "I4", tbElectronicSN, xlSheet);
```

Comment: Please post the code in question.

Comment: public void inputData(int row, int column, string cellName, System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox, Excel.Worksheet sheet)
        {
            sheet.Cells[row, column] = sheet.get_Range(cellName, Type.Missing).Text + " " + textBox.Text; // adds value to sheet
        }

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to post the code here to make it look like it does in VS. In my template, the cell currently says "Name:" in bold.  Then when I add the name "Aaron Kruger", it adds it in just like I would expect.  But it makes the name "Aaron Kruger" bold also.  I want it to add the name, but not bold it.  There should be a way to have different types of string formats, but in the same cell.

Comment: btw, yes this is coding for excel.  It is a project I am doing for my work.  I am using Microsoft.Office, Interop.Excel and using 12.0

Answer (score 3):

```
Range rng1 = ws.getRange("A1","E10");
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    Range rngTst=rng.cells[i,i];
    for(int j=0;j<rngTst.get_characters().count;j++)
    {
        rngTst.application.activecell.get_characters(j,j).font.color
    }
}
```

or

```
int sFirstFoundAddress = currentFind.FormulaR1C1Local.ToString().IndexOf("NOT FOR CIRCULATION ");

get_Range(excel.Cells[1, 1],
    excel.Cells[1, dtData.Columns.Count])
        .get_Characters(sFirstFoundAddress, 20).Font.Color =
            System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Red);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range%28v=office.11%29.aspx) which gives you each character as [Characters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.characters_members%28v=office.11%29.aspx) type. Now use its Font and other properties to style them.

Refer an example here: http://www.bloodforge.com/post/Extract-Formatted-Text-From-Excel-Cell-With-C.aspx

```
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range Range = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)Cell;
   int TextLength = Range.Text.ToString().Length;
   for (int CharCount = 1; CharCount <= TextLength; CharCount++)
   {
       Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Characters charToTest = Range.get_Characters(CharCount, 1);
       bool IsBold = (bool)charToTest.Font.Bold;
       bool IsItalic = (bool)charToTest.Font.Italic;
       // other formatting tests here

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I recorded a macro, it shouldn't be hard to translate it to C#:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Test test"
Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Test test"
With ActiveCell.Characters(Start:=1, Length:=5).Font
    .Name = "Calibri"
    .FontStyle = "Regular"
    .Size = 11
    .Strikethrough = False
    .Superscript = False
    .Subscript = False
    .OutlineFont = False
    .Shadow = False
    .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontMinor
End With
With ActiveCell.Characters(Start:=6, Length:=4).Font
    .Name = "Calibri"
    .FontStyle = "Bold"
    .Size = 11
    .Strikethrough = False
    .Superscript = False
    .Subscript = False
    .OutlineFont = False
    .Shadow = False
    .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontMinor
End With
```