# C# Insert hyperlink into a cell full of text

Tags: c#, excel, cells

Alright i'm having trouble making a small piece of text within a paragraph of text into a hyperlink inside of an excel cell using C#.

this is basically what i have

```
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add(Anchor: Convert.ToString(Cells(39,2).Value), Address: "http://www.google.com", TextToDisplay: "www.google.com");
```

i did have it inserting the link into the cell but it was overwriting the rest of the paragraph. Can someone give me a direction to go in, where i can insert the link without erasing the rest of the paragraph?

Comment: Excel does not support having a hyperlink as only part of the cell.  You'll need to set the whole text of the cell as the `TextToDisplay`

Comment: what do you mean, cause i can easily just select the cell Cells(39, 2).Select() and then change Anchor: Con... into Anchor: Selection   and that will select the cell and put a hyperlink in it, but then i lose all the other information

Comment: ah i think i missunderstood you

Comment: The hyperlink applies to the whole cell.  You could _format_ part of the cell differently to make it _look_ like a hyperlink is embedded but the hyperlink itself applies to the whole cell.

Comment: alright, then how do i format the other text? I am having a hard time just selecting it, or rather figuring out how to select it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667842/multiple-formats-in-one-cell-using-c-sharp