# How can I change color of text in a cell of MS Excel?

Tags: c#, excel

I am using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` library.

I have a cell with values "Green Red". What I want is pretty simple. I want to insert "Green" text to be green and "Red" to be red, like that:

[image]

I am using this code to insert data in cell:

```
Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();
excelApp.Workbooks.Add();
// single worksheet
Excel._Worksheet workSheet = excelApp.ActiveSheet;

for (int startIndex = 0; startIndex < 10; startIndex++)
{
    workSheet.Cells[1, (startIndex + 1)] ="Green" + " Red";
}
```

How to do it?

I've [tried this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2452417/cell-color-changing-in-excel-using-c-sharp), but I do not know what `[RangeObject]` is:

`[RangeObject].Font.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Red);`

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667842/multiple-formats-in-one-cell-using-c-sharp help you - which way of the Excel integration from C# are you using?

Comment: @weismat ooops, I cannot understand your question.I am using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` library.

Comment: Look at:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2452417/cell-color-changing-in-excel-using-c-sharp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2452417/cell-color-changing-in-excel-using-c-sharp)

Comment: @AdamCalvetBohl yeah, I've tried, but cannot figure out what `[RangeObject]` is.

Comment: @StepUp  I'm not familiar with your language, but In Excel VBA, one would use the `Characters` property of the `Range` object to change the font of individual characters within a text string in a cell.  Does that help?

Comment: A range object `Represents a cell, a row, a column, a selection of cells containing one or more contiguous blocks of cells, or a 3-D range.`  For your case applying two colors to one cell it would not be useful.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try:

```
workSheet.Cells[1, (i + 1)].Characters[start_pos, len].Font.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Red);
```

where `start_pos` and `len` is the part of the string where to apply color.

Your use case example:

```
    Application excelApp = new Application();
    excelApp.Workbooks.Add();
    // single worksheet
    _Worksheet workSheet = excelApp.ActiveSheet;

    string Green = "Green";
    string Red = "Red";
    for (int start = 0; start < 10; start++)
    {
        Range ColorMeMine = workSheet.Cells[1, (start + 1)];
        ColorMeMine.Value = string.Format("{0} {1}", Green, Red);
        ColorMeMine.Characters[0, Green.Length].Font.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Green);
        ColorMeMine.Characters[Green.Length + 1, Green.Length + 1 + Red.Length].Font.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Red);
    }
```

Comment: what is  `Range`? What's a library should I use to get `Range` class?

Comment: A Range "Represents a cell, a row, a column, a selection of cells containing one or more contiguous blocks of cells, or a 3-D range". You find it in Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel namespace.

Comment: Cool, this is working just fine. Just remember to add System.Drawing as a reference.